# Process POST data in microhttp server in C

Tags: c, string, http, http-post

I have the following code to process the POST data in the microhttp server:

```
#include <microhttpd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define PAGE "<html><head><title>libmicrohttpd demo</title>"\
             "</head><body>libmicrohttpd demo!!</body></html>"

struct postStatus {
    bool status;
    char *buff;
};


static int ahc_echo(void * cls,
            struct MHD_Connection * connection,
            const char * url,
            const char * method,
                    const char * version,
            const char * upload_data,
            size_t * upload_data_size,
                    void ** ptr) {
  const char * page = cls;
  struct MHD_Response * response;
  int ret;

  struct postStatus *post = NULL;
  post = (struct postStatus*)*ptr;

  if(post == NULL) {
    post = malloc(sizeof(struct postStatus));
    post->status = false;
    *ptr = post;
  }

  if(!post->status) {
    post->status = true;
    return MHD_YES;
  } else {
    if(*upload_data_size != 0) {
        post->buff = malloc(*upload_data_size + 1);
        snprintf(post->buff, *upload_data_size,"%s",upload_data);
        *upload_data_size = 0;
        return MHD_YES;
    } else {
        printf("Post data: %s\n",post->buff);
        free(post->buff);
    }
  } 

  if(post != NULL)
    free(post);

  response = MHD_create_response_from_buffer (strlen(page),
                                              (void*) page,
                          MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);
  ret = MHD_queue_response(connection,
               MHD_HTTP_OK,
               response);
  MHD_destroy_response(response);
  return ret;
}

int main(int argc,
     char ** argv) {
  struct MHD_Daemon * d;

  d = MHD_start_daemon(MHD_USE_SELECT_INTERNALLY,
               9000,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               &ahc_echo,
               PAGE,
               MHD_OPTION_END);
  if (d == NULL)
    return 1;
  sleep(10000);
  MHD_stop_daemon(d);
  return 0;
}
```

I try the following CURL command to test the POST data processing:

```
curl -XPOST -d '{"email":"test@gmail.com","password":"test"}' 'http://192.168.1.17:9000'
```

But I get the output `{"email":"test@gmail.com","password":"test"`. I don't get the last `}`. I tried larger length json inputs also. Still the same. Can't get the last curly brace. Can somebody please help out?

Thanks

EDIT: I got it working. I used `strncpy(post->buff, upload_data, *upload_data_size)` instead of `snprintf`.

Could someone please explain why didn't snprintf work?

Answer (score 1):

ahc_echo() will be called at least two times for the request. The request data might be split up into multiple calls, and this fragmentation is very random (depends on how that request is buffered, and what each read() call on the socket returns). So your current code will only work with small requests, but are still unsafe.

MHD_create_post_processor() is a helper for parsing this partial buffers.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/tutorial.html#Processing-POST-data goes throught this

The reason

```
 snprintf(post->buff, *upload_data_size,"%s",upload_data);
```

does not work, is that it should have been

```
 snprintf(post->buff, *upload_data_size + 1,"%s",upload_data);
```

in order to match the memory size used in malloc(), which has room for the \0 termination.

```
strncpy(post->buff, upload_data, *upload_data_size);
```

Is actually dangerous, since it should have been

```
strncpy(post->buff, upload_data, *upload_data_size);
post->buff[*upload_data_size] = 0;
```

Since you need to make sure the result is zero terminated (it is just lucky that memory contains a zero already now, this is random behaviour when using `malloc()`, and not `calloc()`), and increasing the copy size to `*upload_data_size + 1` would be wrong, since that would overflow the source by one byte, which also contains random data, or maybe even invalid memory.

Comment: While this is a somewhat helpful comment, the MHD postprocessor - which you might expect to parse the required headers like Content-Length, supports a limited set of Content-Type, and notably doesn't support "application/json". If you try to receive "application/json", and you've used this method, microhttpd will terminate the connection.

Comment: Brian Bulkowski - Is there any way to handle it for JSON content?